# Nomad : Unable to Run a python script

Tags: python, scheduler, nomad

I am trying to submit the following job to my nomad server. The job basically uses a payload which is a python file from my localhost.

```
job "agent-collector-bot" {
  datacenters = ["staging"]

  type = "batch"

  periodic {
    cron             = "*/10 * * * *"
    prohibit_overlap = true
  }

  group "python-bot" {
    count = 1
    task "slack-bot" {
      driver = "raw_exec"

      config {
        command = "python"
        args = ["local/agent-collector-slackbot.py"]
      }

      dispatch_payload {
       file = "agent-collector-slackbot.py"
     }

    }
  }
}
```

Now when i see the job status in nomad it says:

snomad status agent-collector-bot/

```
ID            = agent-collector-bot/periodic-1512465000
Name          = agent-collector-bot/periodic-1512465000
Submit Date   = 12/05/17 14:40:00 IST
Type          = batch
Priority      = 50
Datacenters   = staging
Status        = pending
Periodic      = false
Parameterized = false

Summary
Task Group  Queued  Starting  Running  Failed  Complete  Lost
python-bot  1       0         0        0       0         0

Placement Failure
Task Group "python-bot":
  * Constraint "missing drivers" filtered 5 nodes
```

I checked my nomad clients (all 5) are having python on it.. can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

The driver specified in the output is `raw_exec`, not python.

You need to enable it in your client config ([nomad raw_exec docs](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/raw_exec.html))

```
client {
  options = {
    "driver.raw_exec.enable" = "1"
  }
}
```